# Как получить название функции изнутри в Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Нужно просто вывести в чат название функции, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?
Наподобие такого кода:

```py
async def whatitis(ctx):
    await ctx.send(command.name)
```

Мне нужен код такой же простоты, главное получить название команды, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать.

Comment: То-есть вам всё-таки нужно название команды, а не функции?

Comment: Так разве название команды и функции это не одно и тоже? Но в целом, в данном случае мне нужно название команды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавайте вопрос чуть более корректно, а то непонятно что именно вам нужно:

> Нужно просто вывести в чат название функции

> главное получить название команды

---

Если вам нужно название функции, то его можно получить из объекта команды также, как вы получаете имя команды.

Открываем документацию по объекту [`discord.ext.commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command)

И видим здесь и имя команды и объект фукнции-обработчика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Имея объект функции, можем получить ее имя:

```py
@bot.command(name='command_name')
async def func_name(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.reply(f'Имя команды: `{ctx.command.name}` \
                    \nИмя функции: `{ctx.command.callback.__name__}`')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]